# Почему в цикле выводиться одинаковые значения при использования функции min и max?

Tags: python, while, max, min

Нужно написать программу, в которой можно вводить рост, а после выведет Сумму, Минимальное значение и максимальное.

Код:

```
znach = 1
sum = 0

while True:
    a = int(input("Введите рост ученика: "))
    

    if a > 0:
        sum+=a
        m = min([a])
        u = max([a])

    if a == 0:
        znach = znach + 1
        print(f"Введено значений: {znach}")
        print(f"Суммарный рост: {sum}")
        print(f"Минимальный рост: {m}")
        print(f"Максимальный рост: {u}")
```

Comment: Потому что min и max от одного числа и есть это самое число.

Comment: Список нужно пополнять, а не делать каждый раз `min` и `max` из нового списка из одного элемента. И не называйте свою переменную `sum` - это встроенная переменная.

Comment: Как тогда исправить?

Answer (score 1):

1. сначала накопите значения

   ```
    arr = []

    while True:
        a = int(input("Введите рост ученика: "))
        if a == 0:
            break
        arr.append(a)
   ```
2. и лишь затем ищите максимумы и минимумы (так удобнее)

   ```
    print(min(arr), max(arr), sum(arr))
   ```

для задач в которых не вводятся миллионы значений - это оптимальный вариант

Ну или обрабатывайте каждое значение в цикле

```
    a_max = None
    while True:
        a = int(input("Введите рост ученика: "))
        if a == 0:
            break

        if a > a_max or a_max is None:
            a_max = a
```

Comment: Спасибо! В процессе проверки, произошла еще одна ошибка. Если ты ввел 3 числа, выводится в принте значения 4

Comment: не понял, пример приведите для удобства понимания